# Trace minimization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Is it true that for a fixed positive definite $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a positive definite $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ ($M$ and $T$ are to be chosen),
\begin{align*}
\text{Tr}(C(MCM^\top T^{-1}+I)^{-1})
\end{align*}
is minimized when the eigenvalues of $MT^{-1}M^\top$ are maximized.

**My intuition:**

- If we were to simplify the matrices to just single variables (i.e., $1\times1$ matrices), the goal would simply become minimizing $\frac{C}{M^2C/T+1}=\frac{1}{M^2/T+1/C}$, which holds when $\frac{M^2}{T}$ is maximized.
- If they are all diagonal matrices, then the above is also true.
- I also thought of using Woodbury matrix identity to simplify the above equation but got stuck:
  \begin{align*}
  \text{Tr}(C(MCM^\top T^{-1}+I)^{-1})
  &=\text{Tr}(CT(MCM^\top+T)^{-1}) \\
  &=\text{Tr}(CT(T^{-1}-T^{-1}M(C^{-1}+M^\top T^{-1}M)^{-1}M^\top T^{-1})) \\
  &=\text{Tr}(C(I-M(C^{-1}+M^\top T^{-1}M)^{-1}M^\top T^{-1})) \\
  &=\text{Tr}(C)-\text{Tr}(CM(C^{-1}+M^\top T^{-1}M)^{-1}M^\top T^{-1}) \\
  &=\text{Tr}(C)-\text{Tr}(CM^\top T^{-1}M(C^{-1}+M^\top T^{-1}M)^{-1}).
  \end{align*}
  Then minimizing the above is just maximizing $\text{Tr}(CM^\top T^{-1}M(C^{-1}+M^\top T^{-1}M)^{-1})$ since $C$ is fixed. I got stuck at this point.

Comment: Is $C$ or $M$ invertible? We can add the constraint to design such that $M$ be invertible anyway, but how about $C$? is $C$ invertible? For Invertible $C$ solution is easy and straightforward I guess!
By the way problem might be infeasible or unbounded above!

Comment: Yes C is invertible. Assuming C and M are invertible, how do you do it?

Comment: Also how do you "add the constraint to design such that M be invertible anyway"? Thank you so much.

Comment: Nope, it's not trivial at all! Sorry, got the order of multiplication wrong. Is this problem from somewhere?

Comment: I see. The non-matrix version of the problem is something I read as part of the proof in a paper, where $M^2/T$ is just the signal to noise ratio. I was just wondering if we could extend it to matrices.

Comment: Is there anything else we can say about $M$ and $T$ when $\text{Tr}(C(MCM^\top T^{-1}+I)^{-1})$ is minimized?

Comment: I don't know exactly to be honest. Try to solve problem for $n=2$ case to get some intuition on possible solutions. Otherwise try to impose more structure on problem until you can simplify it, for example what happens if $M$ be orthogonal. These kind of problems which arise from physical systems rarely get a satisfying simple solution, it's always a guaranteed torment.